# XSLT - Ignore/Remove the empty namespace in the child node

Tags: xml, xslt

In order to be able to be able to have a `root` element with a *dynamic* namespace value I switched it from: `<Foo xmlns="HardCodedXMLNS">` to:
`<xsl:element name="Foo" namespace="{Table/Foo_Dynamic_XMLNS}">`

The current XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
        <xsl:element name="Foo" namespace="{Table/Foo_xmlns}">
            <Bar Id ="{Table/Bar_Id}">
            </Bar>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now the problem is that the `<Bar>` element gets an empty namespace after transformation like this **(Current output)**:

```
<Foo xmlns="http://MyDynamicValue">
    <Bar xmlns="">
    </Bar>
</Foo>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<Foo xmlns="http://MyDynamicValue">
    <Bar>
    </Bar>
</Foo>
```

**Question:** How would one solve this problem so that the `Bar` node doesn't have the namespace?

Comment: It isn't clear if you just don't like the `xmlns=""` appearing on the element that is not bound to a namespace, or if you want it to also be bound to the same namespace as it's parent. Can you update your question with an example of the desired output?

Comment: @MadsHansen Question have been updated with a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the principle is: if you put the elements in the right namespace, the namespace declarations will look after themselves. The reason you have an `xmlns=""` declaration on the child is that you created the child element as a no-namespace element.

(If you want actual code in the answer, then put some code in the question. In particular, your title talks about setting the namespace dynamically, but you haven't explained whether it really needs to be dynamic).

Comment: You're certainly right and I have updated my question and hopefully it becomes more clear now.

Comment: Thanks, your code makes clear that you are creating the Foo element in a namespace, and the Bar element in no namespace, and this is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your elements have different namespace values. Without using namespace prefixes, the `xmlns` namespace binding attribute is required in order to express what the namespace value is for those elements.

The element named **root** is bound to the namespace **MyNS** and the element named **child** is in the "no namespace" and has none.

Since the parent element is bound to a namespace and does not use a namespace-prefix, it's child element - which has no namespace, will have the empty namespace declaration. The **xmlns** namespace declaration attribute is present to indicate what the namespace is (or to indicate that it has none).

Otherwise, if your XML was:

```
<root xmlns="MyNS">
  <child />
</root>
```

then the **child** element would be bound to the "**MyNS**" namespace. It would be the equivalent of:

```
<m:root xmlns:m="MyNS">
  <m:child/>
</m:root>
```

If the element named **root** had a namespace prefix, then you could have the output, in which the element named **root** is bound to the **MyNS** namespace and the element named **child** has no namespace and does not need the empty namespace declaration `xmlns=""`:

```
<m:root xmlns:m="MyNS">
  <child/>
</m:root>
```