# Empty namespace in child node

Tags: xml, xslt

When using a fixed namespace the output is correct.

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
        <Foo namespace="http://MyLink/FixedVersion">
            <Bar>
                <SomeData/>
            </Bar>
        </Foo>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo namespace="http://MyLink/FixedVersion">
    <Bar>
        <SomeData />
    </Bar>
</Foo>
```

When using a dynamic namespace the namespace in the child nodes' namespace gets set with an empty value.

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
        <xsl:element name="Foo" namespace="http://MyLink/{Table/version}">
            <Bar>
                <SomeData/>
            </Bar>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo xmlns="http://MyLink/v02_04_01">
    <Bar xmlns="">
        <SomeData />
    </Bar>
</Foo>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49872085/2524586 states that they are in different namespaces but I don't understand how a fixed and dynamic value can change that.

My expected result is having the first output but with a dynamic `version` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have to create namespaces explicitly on every element. Your error in the first example was that you didn't create a namespace at all:

```
<Foo namespace="http://MyLink/FixedVersion">
    <Bar>
        <SomeData />
    </Bar>
</Foo>
```

Here `Foo` has no namespace assigned to it:
see, it has no `xmlns="..."` namespace attribute (!) but a (rather arbitrary) `namespace="..."` attribute.

So the only way to achieve your desired result is to add a `namespace="..."` attribute on every `xsl:element`:

```
<xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <xsl:element name="Foo" namespace="http://MyLink/{Table/version}">
        <xsl:element name="Bar" namespace="http://MyLink/{Table/version}">
            <xsl:element name="SomeData" namespace="http://MyLink/{Table/version}" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Foo xmlns="http://MyLink/v02_04_01">
    <Bar>
        <SomeData/>
    </Bar>
</Foo>
```

Comment: +1 - I was just about to answer similarly. Feel free to use my fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyW

Answer (score 2):

The expanded name of an element (that is, the (namespace, local-name) pair) is determined entirely by the instruction that creates the element; it doesn't depend in any way on the element's parent in the result tree. You can never rely on an element going into the same namespace as its parent.

For a literal result element such as `<Foo>` or `<p:Bar>`, the expanded name of the element in the result tree is the same as the expanded name of the element in the stylesheet. That is, it's determined by the rules of the XML namespaces spec: the namespace URI is determined by xmlns namespace declarations in the stylesheet (which can appear on the literal result element itself, or on any ancestor element). That means in turn that the namespace is a static constant, it can't be computed dynamically.

For an element constructed using xsl:element, there are two ways of specifying the namespace. If a `namespace` attribute is present, then its effective value (interpreted as an AVT) establishes the namespace URI of the constructed element. Because this is an AVT, the namespace can be computed dynamically.

In the absence of a `namespace` attribute, the value of the `name` attribute is interpreted as a lexical QName and the namespace is determined in the same way as for a literal result element, using the namespace declarations that are in scope for the `xsl:element` instruction in the stylesheet. With this mechanism you can choose dynamically between a fixed set of statically known namespaces, but you can't compute the namespace entirely dynamically:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:a="http://one-uri/" xmlns:b="http://another-uri/">
....
   <xsl:element name="{if (x) then 'a' else 'b'}:foo">
```